# How to create bounce effect on ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a page on which there are menus. when you select menu(mouse hover or mouse move) a drop down ul appears. Here is the code

```
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myBounce.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="menubg">      
            <ul class="dropdown">   
                <li><a href="#">Really Tall Menu</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Basit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Masood</a></li>
                         ...                     
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Kinda Tall Menu</a>
                    <ul id="test">
                        <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                        ..
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>       
    </div>
</body>
```

js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js contains the bounce effect. I want that when my ul appears , it appears with bounce effect. I have many ul on my page. In myBounce.js i used the following code, but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").effect("bounce");
});
```

How can i create bounce effect on ul?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it on the div container?

Comment: I would use the easing thats a part of jquery ui, combined with animate(); http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: @Johan I have also jquery.easing.1.3.js. But how can i use it to creat bounce effect, using animate?

Comment: @Steve No, i didn't. Is it necessary to use it on div? You mean i put my ul inside div ?

Comment: Beside the point, but it looks like you are including jquery twice? Purposely? js/jquery-1.7.1.js and js/jquery.min.js

Comment: @TJ I have now just 3 files `jquery-1.7.1.js, jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js, jquery.dropdown.js, myBounce.js`. If i remove the file **jquery.dropdown.js ** . Then when i open the page then my menus are not hidden. So it is necessary to use this file. But still no bounce

Comment: @Basit Have a look at my answer below. You can use css to hide the sub menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the advanced jQuery ui [show](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/) method to add the effectwhen you show your ul

```
$( "#id_of_your_ul" ).show( 'bounce');
```

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").show("bounce");
});` I am including the following file `jquery-1.7.1.js, jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js, jquery.dropdown.js, myBounce.js`

Comment: @Basit have you included jQuery ui and have you hidden your ul before showing them? http://jsfiddle.net/9dq6W/

Comment: jquey ui. You mean jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js? Actually `jquery.dropdown.js` hides the menu. If i remove this, then the menus show continue to show.

Comment: Ont thing more that when i downlaoded the jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js. Ijust tick the effect check box. Means my ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js contains only effect. Do ineed to downlaod full Ui?

Comment: @Basit yes i think you should download the full UI

Answer (score 0):

Using your html, try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('ul.dropdown > li > a').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).closest('li').children('ul').show().effect('bounce');
       });
    });
</script>
```